# How to detect mobile hotspot feature availability in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I hope title itself says what my question is...

For example, We can check the Wifi availability with PackageManager like

```
packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI);
```

Similarly is there any way to detect Mobile hotspot feature availability in Android programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Since for switching on/off wifi-hotspot there do not exist any API calls, I don't think there is a general method/way to detect presence of hotspot... but just my guess

Comment: The thing that I'm sure about is that there's no official API for android hotspot usage. You may find this [WifiApManger](https://github.com/nickrussler/Android-Wifi-Hotspot-Manager-Class) class useful.

Answer (score 4):

i went through google documentation and found that if wifi P2P is supported by device then its obvious it suports wifi hotspot

to check Wi-Fi Direct/ wifi P2P by device then check this way

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
     if (!m.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_DIRECT)) {
            // This device does support wifi P2P
        }
```

but google says its better to check for this support in your broadcast receiver itself this way

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            // Wifi P2P is enabled
        } else {
            // Wi-Fi P2P is not enabled
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

check [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#creating-app) for same

Answer (score 1):

The is maybe the first step to the solution.

See:
[Android Wifi Hotspot Manager Class](https://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class)

Comment: Thanks!!! with this class, We can enable or disable hotspot. but how to detect its availibiity?

Comment: Try to enable/disable in a device that is not supported, and see if any exception is thrown. See too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401108/how-to-check-programmatically-if-hotspot-is-enabled-or-disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by calling this: `ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered()`

This will return current active connection in Wifi Hotspot or not .

I think its a little bit helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this information by calling `ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered()`.

This will return whether the active connection is a hotspot (as defined in Data Usage -> Mobile Hotspots).

Here is a good answer on similar question!!! 
[How to detect if a network is (configured as) a mobile hotspot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514387/how-to-detect-if-a-network-is-configured-as-a-mobile-hotspot-on-android)