# How to find if the device is configured as a portable hotspot

Tags: android, android-wifi, hotspot

I can't find in the doc how to retrieve if device is configured as a portable hotspot.

I've read [How to detect if a network is (configured as) a mobile hotspot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514387/how-to-detect-if-a-network-is-configured-as-a-mobile-hotspot-on-android) but I don't know if the feature has been implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to check if Tethering is enabled or not on your device:

```
private static Method isWifiApEnabledMethod;

public static boolean isWifiApEnabled(WifiManager wifiManager) {
    if (isWifiApEnabledMethod == null) {
        try {
            isWifiApEnabledMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
            isWifiApEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true); //in the case of visibility change in future APIs
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Can't get method by reflection", e);
        }
    }

    if (isWifiApEnabledMethod != null) {
        try {
            return (Boolean) isWifiApEnabledMethod.invoke(wifiManager);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't invoke method by reflection", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't invoke method by reflection", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Don't forget to add below permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

---

*For the SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514387/how-to-detect-if-a-network-is-configured-as-a-mobile-hotspot-on-android) mentioned above in question:*

This feature is **not available** i.e. has not been implemented.
For more information check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36999124) link where Google officially marked the status as *Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)*

Comment: The above code tells me if my device is connected to a portable hotspot, not if my device is the access point, right? Why is the status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)? Thanks for the info update and sharing the code :)